# Semaphore and alternating printing

Tags: c, synchronization, fork, parent-child, semaphore

I want the following: first the parent process prints "hello", then the child process prints "world" and this is done 3 times. When I execute my code I only get hello world once but I want to get it printed 3 times.

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
        char* parent="hello ";
        char* child="world";

        sem_t *sem = sem_open("/mysem", O_CREAT, 0644, 1);

        sem_t *sem1=sem_open("/mysem1", O_CREAT, 0644, 0);

        int pid=fork();
        if(pid<0){
                printf("error in forking");
                return -1;
        }
        int cnt=0, cnt1=0;

        if(pid==0){
                sem_wait(sem1);
                write(1, child, strlen(child));
                cnt++;
                if(cnt1<3){
                        sem_post(sem);
                }
        }else{
                sem_wait(sem);
                write(1, parent, strlen(parent));
                cnt++;
                if(cnt<3){
                        sem_post(sem1);
                }
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any loop in your code, why would you expect to see the output 3 times?

Comment: But I want them to alternate - first the parent process prints, then the child, then the parent again, then the child, etc...

Answer (score 1):

maybe try this :

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 7

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    char parent[BUFFER_SIZE] = "hello ";
    char child[BUFFER_SIZE] = "world\n";
    sem_t *sem = sem_open("/mysem", O_CREAT, 0644, 1);
    sem_t *sem1 = sem_open("/mysem1", O_CREAT, 0644, 0);
    int cnt = 0;
    int pid = fork();

    if (sem == SEM_FAILED || sem1 == SEM_FAILED) {
        printf("Error : sem_open() call failed.\n");
        return (-1);
    }
    if (pid < 0) {
        printf("error in forking");
        return (-1);
    }

    if (pid == 0) {
        while (cnt < 3) {
            sem_wait(sem1);
            if (write(1, child, strlen(child)) == -1) {
                printf("Error : write call failed.\n");
            }
            cnt++;
            sem_post(sem);
        }
    }
    else {
        while (cnt < 3) {
            sem_wait(sem);
            if (write(1, parent, strlen(parent)) == -1) {
                printf("Error : write function failed.\n");
            }
            cnt++;
            sem_post(sem1);
        }
    }
    sem_close(sem);
    sem_close(sem1);
    return (0);
}
```

**Explanation :**

1. `#define BUFFER_SIZE 7` this is a [macro](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-preprocessor-macros), 7 because of part 2.
2. Memory leaks (*use valgrind*)

   Don't do : `char *str = "abc";`

   but do : `char str[string_size + 1] = "abc";`

   Because `char *str =` doesn't allocate memory so you will probably get memory leaks,  always allocate string_size + 1 with [C String](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm). You can use [malloc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) too to allocate your own size.
3. Put your `int cnt` variables before the `fork()`, fork will copy all memory so you can put only one variable before your fork call, for more readable code.
4. You should always call [sem_close()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_close.3.html) as soon as possible and you should always look for returned value from functions that are not your, use C man, for exmaple "man 2 write" in your linux console (not looking for sem_wait semp_post and sem_close returned value shouldn't be problematic here, but you can still print a message if you want).
5. Your main problem here is that you should switch your `if (cnt < 3)` into a loop as i did with `while`, your parent and child process only course once write() if you don't set a loop.
6. The most important thing, please look for coding style rules to make your code more redeable.

**This is pretty long, but you should take at look in all i said.**

**Compilation :**

```
gcc file.c -pthread
./a.out
```

I'm on linux, fedora32.

**Output :**

```
hello world
hello world
hello world
```

Comment: Nope, infinity cycle :)

Comment: I tried this code and it work fine for me.

Comment: How do you execute the code then? ./file.c ?

Comment: I don't know what environment do you use, your main problem here is that your "if (cnt < 3)" as no loop, it course only once. You can try to learn some documentation on C coding style to get your code more readable. (trying my best with my english level ^)

Comment: @Vanessa If you compile without specifying the name of the output file, then the default name `a.out` is used, and you run the program with `./a.out`

Comment: Okay, thank you, but the output I get is hello hello hello world :(

Comment: @Vanessa I solved some memory leaks in the code, please try again with it.

Comment: Now I get hello hello hello world world

Comment: @Vanessa with "char *str = "abc";" you don't allocate memory, you must use like this "char str[4] = "abc";", 4 and not 3 because you should not forget '\0' that terminate a string in C. You can do "char *str = malloc(4);" then set the characters 1 by 1 too.

Comment: @Vanessa I can't help you much since my code is working and not your, did you copy all my code ? try to update your question with more informations, for example valgrind output ect... maybe some screenshots.

Comment: Code without explanation is not a good answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I added explanations, let me know if it's ok for you.